# Is there any way to evaluate RMSE and MAE on out of bag data for random forest regressor

Tags: python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vugWW.png)I am working with random forest regression model for my thesis work. My data set is small (about 3000 samples and 20 features) and it's over fitting on train data. Since data set is small and i don't want to split data into train(train+oob), test sets.So I am using a bagging regression to avoid over fitting problem. 
 I'm trying to evaluate performance metrics for regression model. I can calculate RMSE and MAE values for train set but I don't know how to check these metrics for out of bag data. Need suggestions
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your setup so far so that we can help?

Comment: bagging = BaggingRegressor(RandomForestRegressor(),n_estimators=500,
                      bootstrap=True,oob_score=True)
bagging.fit(X_prepared,y)